# Unable to register OpsHub OVSMU

Tags: opshub

The installer is getting a 503 while connecting the following URL:

http://www.opshub.com/ohftp/InstallationVerifier/NewCustomerEntry.php

[image]

Comment: Yes, we are currently in midst of server maintenance. The issue should be resolved soon. We'll give you a an update once it is back online

Comment: Hello, the server up-gradation is complete. It is highly recommended you download the latest version of OVSMU from the gallery page and continue with your installation and migration. (Older versions of installer will not longer work)